# Could I use Revert after abrupting Merge?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Hallo all,

Just now I tried to upload a modified working copy to its branch in the following steps:
1. Update
2. Commit
Then I attempted to Merge the changes in the trunk to this branch. However during editing of the conflicts I realized there were so many conflicting codes that I could not address completely today, then I gived up the Merge, and the working copy got an exclamation mark immediately. Thru Check for modifications I found that many many files had been modified or had conflicts. It seems that the Merge has been somehow wrongly carried out. My question: could I return to the state before the Merge simply using Revert?

Thanks a lot in advance,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem since merge is done in your working copy.

However, I do sometimes have to issue cleanup or in extreme cases even a clean checkout (sometimes it gets really messy). Luckily your changes are safely committed so you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Luc, should I make Clean up afte Revert?

Comment: No, cleanup is used in exceptional circumstances when there was a problem with an action, i.e. update didn't finish right. It will try to repair your working copy and TSVN will usually even inform you when to do it.

Otherwise I really suggest you go over the TSVN help file; at least "Daily use guide" and "How do I" parts.